# How to translate Morse Code to English in C++?

Tags: c++

I am currently trying to find a way to create a function to translate morse code to english. Here's my code (NOTE: NOT THE WHOLE CODE)

```cpp
int main()
{
    string const morseCode[] = {".-", "-...", "-.-.", "-..", ".", "..-.",
    "--.", "....", "..", ".---", "-.-", ".-..", "--", "-.", "---", ".--.", "--.-",
    ".-.", "...", "-", "..-", "...-", ".--", "-..-", "-.--", "--..", ".----", "..---", "...--", "....-", 
    ".....", "-....", "--...", "---..", "----.", "-----", " ", " "};
 
    string const englishLetter[] = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", 
    "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", 
    "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", "", " "};
}

string convertToEnglish(string morse, string const morseCode[], string const alpha[])
{
    string output;
    string compile;
    string currentCodeLetter;
    int totalMorseCode=38;
    string str = morse;

    for(int position=0; position<str.size(); ++position)  //tried to do the same as englishtomorse but i guess it need a little fix
    {
        currentCodeLetter = str[position];

        for(int marker=0; marker<totalMorseCode; marker++)      
        {
            if(currentCodeLetter==morseCode[marker])
            {
                compile = alpha[marker];
            }
        }

        output += compile + "   ";
    }

    return output;
}
```

The string `morse` is the input from the user. The instruction for the user is to leave a blank space between morse code letters, and three blank spaces between morse code words.

The problem is, when I type in for example `".-"`, which is supposed to be `A` in text , the output would be `E` and `T` which are `"."` and `"-"`.

How to differentiate between morse codes, since they are only using `"-"` and `"."`? Please don't suggest me to use `std::map` because I haven't learned that in my class yet, or maybe never, or any unusual header file. I only have 5 days left to submit the code.

Comment: also is it true that one morse code in the string array considered as like one element?  if yes why it can't just match the right one?

Comment: I would use an ```std::unordered_map<std::string, char>``` that maps morse code to English characters. You can then iterate through each morse code element and look up the english character in the aforementioned hash map and add it to the final english string.

Comment: @PolarToCartesian Why is there need for a ```std::ordered_map```? Why not use ```std::unordered_map```?

Comment: @TomGebel It's a typo, sorry, thanks I'll edit it.

Comment: Did you read some [good C++ programming book](https://www.stroustrup.com/programming.html) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing here is you are not splitting the code into letters using " " as the separator. Try this,

```
string convertToEnglish(string morse, string const morseCode[], string const alpha[])

{
  string output;
  string compile;
  string currentCodeLetter;
  int totalMorseCode=38;
  string str = morse;

  istringstream iss(str); // This is kinda a hack.
  
  while ( getline( iss, currentCodeLetter, ' ' ) )
  {    
        for(int marker=0;marker<totalMorseCode;marker++) 
            if(currentCodeLetter==morseCode[marker]) 
                compile = alpha[marker]; 

        output += compile + "   "; 
        compile = "";
   }

   return output;
}
```

For a more optimal solution just google how to split a string by " ", StackOverflow has already gotten your back :).

---

### Detecting 3 whitespaces

```
string convertToEnglish(string morse, string const morseCode[], string const alpha[])

{
  string output;
  string compile;
  string currentCodeLetter;
  int totalMorseCode=38;
  string str = morse;
  String prev;  

  istringstream iss(str); // This is kinda a hack.

  while ( getline( iss, currentCodeLetter, ' ' ) )
  {    
        for(int marker=0;marker<totalMorseCode;marker++) 
            if(currentCodeLetter==morseCode[marker]) 
                compile = alpha[marker];

        if( currentCodeLetter == " " && prev == " " )
        { // Detecteded 3 spaces do your thing here }
        prev = currentCodeLetter;

        output += compile + "   "; 
        compile = "";
   }

   return output;
}
```

Comment: Why copying `morse` to `str` instead of using `morse` directly?

Comment: @Rohit THANK YOU A LOT FOR YOUR HELP!!! but can you explain the actual point of istringstream?? my understanding about this is that it is used to process a string until a whitespace has reached so its considered as one string. Is this right? Also how to know if the user has entered three blank spaces to separate between two morse code words?

Comment: @bilah Yes, you got it right. I don't understand why you need 3 whitespaces to separate words you could simply use 2 and this will map it to the" " character. But if for some reason you have to use 3 spaces then you have to store the previous character in a variable and when you get a space check whether the previous character was a space.

Comment: If this answer helped it will be greatly appreciated if you could mark it as selected.

Comment: @Rohit what I meant is i need the user to input 3 blank spaces when they try to separate 2 words in morse code for example ".- -.<3 spaces>.- .--. .--. .-.. ." so that in english text it would be "an<1 space>apple"

Comment: @bilah If the user leaves double spaces between words it will automatically be converted to a single space in English. So the idea is you could use a single space to separate letters and double to separate words.

Comment: sorry i did not notice the edit version 23 hours ago. Anyway sorry if im asking too many questions, so what do you I actually write in the if statement if( currentCodeLetter == " " && prev == " " )? @Rohit

Comment: @bilah No amount of questions are ever too much, they just make you and me better.

Comment: @bilah Inside the if block we have detected a break between two morse-code words. Now it is up to you to decide how you want this to reflect in your English translation. You could add a character to separate words ( In the translated version ), many spaces, or any other character you like. To do this set compile to the character you want to use to separate English words ( eg: compile = " " ). What character you use here is completely a design choice and is up to you.

Comment: tried to do exactly like you did in the code with the compile = " " in the if statement, but still didnt work, it detected the three spaces as the previous morse code entered for example ".-   .-" to "A   A   A   A" @Rohit

Comment: @bilah It was a bug. I forgot to add compile = ""; at the end. Now it should work.